# Unexpected keyword 'import' in vue project

Tags: vue.js, axios

I installed axios normally with my atom terminal like `npm install axios` but after importing it in my vue component like `import axios from 'axios'` it returns this error `Unexpected keyword 'import'` after that i imported it in my main.js file but error says `'axios' is defined but never used` any solutions?

Comment: show us the components

Comment: @Liberi https://prnt.sc/sbl4dt everything normal I guess?

Comment: also, show us the error, do you have eslint in your project?

Comment: @Liberi I do have, https://prnt.sc/sblatf this error is when I import axios in my component.

Comment: that is the error you have

Comment: How is the accepted answer different to what you had first with the error being _"Unexpected keyword 'import'"_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is produced by the linter in your project:

```
'axios' is defined but never used
```

As you can see from the screenshot of the error, it says `no-unused-vars`. So all you need to do is to use that module in your code somewhere, for example:

### Body.vue

```js
<script>
  import axios from 'axios'
  ...
  methods: {
    someMethod() {
      axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
       .then((response) => {

       })
    }
  }
</script>
```

Linters are helpful if you want your code to look consistent, but they can be annoying. I would suggest to turn this error into a warning instead.

Create a file called `.eslintrc.js` in the root of your project and in that file specify that it should treat that error as a warning.

Here's an example from my project (node.js + Vue)

```
// use module.exports if you're using node.js, otherwise use JS export notation

module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    '@vue/standard'
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint'
  },
  rules: {
    'no-unused-vars': 'warn'
  }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like exactly what OP had first where they were getting _"Unexpected keyword 'import'"_. I wonder why it works for them now

Comment: @Phil yeah,  I noticed that too, but that `Unexpected keyword 'import'"` error sounds like it was caused by some typo in HTML above the `script` tag, I think OP fixed that error and simply got confused thinking it was also related to Axios. On the last screenshot OP posted in the comments, notice how the `'axios' is defined but never used` error is actually in his `body.vue` component, not in his `main`. I bet they just got confused and mixed in unrelated errors

Answer (score 0):

The error you have is that you imported `Axios` but you didn't use it in your code then vuejs with eslint come with the rules to forcing developers to only import the modules that you are really using if you are not using it don't import it so you could simply do something like this

```
<script>
  import axios from 'axios'
  ...
  methods: {
    getData() {
      axios.get('/posts')
       .then((response) => {

       })
    }
  }
</script>
```

as the error is coming from the selling you can take more about such error on eslint https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars